# How to use variable of batch file into VB script file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have created batch file which include code of batch file as well as code of VBScript. Now I am trying to pass variable value from batch file to VBScript but it does not work.

```
echo This is batch
set /p Name="Enter Your Name: "
:x=msgbox("You have Entered '" & name & "'" ,0, "Your Title Here")
findstr "^:" "%~sf0">temp.vbs & cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp.vbs
echo This is batch again
```

Following output I am getting:

```
c:\Users\vshah\Desktop>echo This is batch
This is batch

c:\Users\vshah\Desktop>set /p Name="Enter Your Name: "
Enter Your Name: Vinkesh

c:\Users\vshah\Desktop>findstr "^:" "c:\Users\vshah\Desktop\Print.bat"  1>temp.vbs  & cscript //nologo temp.vbs   & del temp.vbs

c:\Users\vshah\Desktop>echo This is batch again
This is batch again

c:\Users\vshah\Desktop>

In Message Box I am getting message only -- You have Entered "
Not getting variable output
```

Kindly help me to pass variable from batch code to VBScript code and use them

Thank you very much in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change this:

```
:x=msgbox("You have Entered '" & name & "'" ,0, "Your Title Here")
findstr "^:" "%~sf0">temp.vbs & cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp.vbs
```

into this:

```
echo x=msgbox("You have Entered '%name%'" ,0, "Your Title Here")>temp.vbs
cscript //nologo temp.vbs & del temp.vbs
```

Note that you're not really passing a variable this way, but creating a temporary script that contains the literal value of that variable. If you want the VBScript to actually use a variable you need to change the code to something like this:

```
echo name=WScript.Arguments.Unnamed(0)>temp.vbs
echo x=msgbox("You have Entered '" ^& name ^& "'" ,0, "Your Title Here")>>temp.vbs
cscript //nologo temp.vbs "%name%"
del temp.vbs
```

Answer (score 1):

This generates the correct msgbox:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo This is batch
set /p Name="Enter Your Name: "
:x=msgbox("You have Entered '__name__'" ,0, "Your Title Here")
findstr "^:" "%~sf0"> %TEMP%\str
set /p vbl=<%TEMP%\str
del %TEMP%\str >NUL
set vbl=%vbl:__name__=!name!%
rem remove the first colon
echo %vbl:~1% 1>temp.vbs  & cscript //nologo temp.vbs   & del temp.vbs
```

I have used a template (`__name__`) along with `enabledelayedexpansion` to be able to replace a value by a variable in a variable.
I had to create another temporary file too, that I delete afterwards.